# Sidekiq with Capistrano (2.x) - is needed to set up restarting Sidekiq after every delpoyment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, sidekiq

I am playing with Sidekiq and using Capistrano for deploying the application.

So far I am using the `gem 'capistrano-sidekiq' , group: :development` gem and as I was previously using DelaydedJob, I needed to remove from my current deploy file these lines:

```
set :delayed_job_command, "bin/delayed_job"
after "deploy:start", "delayed_job:start"
after "deploy:stop", "delayed_job:stop"
```

What do I need to add to Capistrano for Sidekiq to make sure Sidekiq will run all the time (means it will not be interrupted/stopped after I deploy some code to server?

Or does the gem automatically (re)starts Sidekiq after every deployment that has been made?

Comment: You want sidekiq to be restarted.  If not then your jobs will have stale code in them.  All of that is run in memory.  So if you update your rails code, just deploying new code won't update what's running in sidekiq.

Comment: did i answer your question below?

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq is restarted automatically in Capistrano 2.x after deployment.

The capistrano-sidekiq gem which manages it says:

```
if fetch(:sidekiq_default_hooks)
    before 'deploy:update_code', 'sidekiq:quiet'
    after 'deploy:stop', 'sidekiq:stop'
    after 'deploy:start', 'sidekiq:start'
    before 'deploy:restart', 'sidekiq:restart'
  end
```

On lines 26-31 of the gem file lib/capistrano/tasks/capistrano2.rb.

:sidekiq_default_hooks is set in the block

```
Capistrano::Configuration.instance.load do

  _cset(:sidekiq_default_hooks) { true }
```

Above it so it is a Capistrano instance variable loaded by the configuration for this particular environment.

The sidekiq:quiet command runs

```
run_as "if [ -d #{current_path} ] && [ -f #{pid_file} ] && kill -0 `cat #{pid_file}`> /dev/null 2>&1; then cd #{current_path} && #{fetch(:sidekiqctl_cmd)} quiet #{pid_file} ; else echo 'Sidekiq is not running'; fi"
```

And I'm assuming by using the default Capistrano 2 deploy configuration your deployment process would look like:
[image: cap deploy proc]

So - based on that you can confirm that it will restart every time. You can manually alter your deployment process using Capistrano 2 if you so choose to do so or you can also alter the :sidekiq_default_hooks variable and define your own Sidekiq process too that way.